# What is an idiom for saying that someone/something is as bad as someone/something else?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

What is an idiom for saying that someone/something is as bad as someone/something else?
For example, when someone praises a particular system but condemns the other, we may say that they are both bad and corrupted.

Comment: ...maybe "calling the kettle  black"?  But this question is unclear and requires more context as well as some research.

Comment: [*Caught between the devil and the deep blue sea*](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/between-the-devil-and-the-deep-blue-sea.html) is one expression relevant to being forced to choose between two equally bad alternatives. But there are many others, so I agree with @Cascabel that we really need more details on the *precise* context.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but you need to clarify what you are asking.  Your question indicates one thing and description talks about something different.  The previous two comments answer your two different questions.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  If you do not edit it to clarify it then it will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @Cascabel, your question is currently a bit unclear. However, if we interpret it as something like this:

**John**: System A is wonderful, and System B is horrible.
**Eric**: Actually, both systems are horrible. [insert idiom]

Then you could use *the grass is always greener on the other side*, or a variant.

From [The Idioms](https://www.theidioms.com/grass-is-always-greener-on-the-other-side/):

> Meaning:
>
> - to think that other’s part is better than mine
> - to believe that someone else’s life is better their own
> - to think that the other person has it easier in a direct competition
> - to think that own job is harder than someone else’s

---

## Examples

**Eric**: Actually, both systems are terrible. The grass is just as stunted on the other side.

*or*

**Eric**: Actually, both systems are terrible. But I guess the grass is always greener [on the other side].

Answer (score 1):

When someone praises a particular system but condemns the other, if we think they're pretty much equal, in practice, we can express this by saying

**Six of one, half a dozen of the other.**

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/six-of-one--half-a-dozen-of-the-other) gives this meaning: "The alternatives are the same" and this example: “During rush hour, it's six of one, half a dozen of the other.”

Answer (score 0):

One possible phrase is "tarred with the same brush". It has been suggested that this has racist connotations, but is more likely to refer to tarring and feathering of criminals or the practice of marking sheep with tar.

**John**: System A is wonderful, and System B is horrible.
**Eric**: Actually, both systems are horrible, *they are tarred with the same brush*.